# Display 3 random Images, without a double displayed one in Java?

Tags: java, android, random, drawable

I already saw a few questions regarding this, but none with java that I could understand, so here's my problem:

I have a an `ArrayList` called `playableCards` with 6 `drawables`:

```
ArrayList<Image> playableCards =new ArrayList<>(
    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    R.drawable.image3,
    R.drawable.image4,
    R.drawable.image5,
    R.drawable.image6);
```

In my Activity I have 3 `ImageViews`: `imageView1` `imageView2` `imageView3`

I need these 3 `ImageViews` to each display one drawable from `playableCards`, but none should be displayed twice.

The `User` can click each `ImageView` and by doing so, one of the remaining drawables of `playableCards` should replace the drawable before.

So if the `User` clicks `imageView1`, which currently displays a random drawable, lets say `R.drawable.image3`, it should change to another drawable of `playableCards` that isn't displayed in the other 2 `ImageViews`...

Does someone know how that is possible?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. the android studio tag is used when you have a question regarding the ide and not just because you're using it to develop your app (as answers won't be any different) so there's no need to add it if you're not asking about the IDE

Comment: secondly, shuffle your list, then take the first item from the list always until nothing remains. you can consider changing your list to another datastructure perhaps to make this task simpler.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using this random selection like below:

```java
ArrayList<Image> playableCards =new ArrayList<>(
    R.drawable.image1,
    R.drawable.image2,
    R.drawable.image3,
    R.drawable.image4,
    R.drawable.image5,
    R.drawable.image6);
Image[] selected = new Image[3];

void randomSelect(){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        int randomSelectedIndex = new Random().nextInt() % (6-i);
        selected[i] = playableCards.get(randomSelectedIndex);
        playableCards.remove(randomSelectedIndex);
    }
}
void onClick(int clickedItemIndex){
    int randomSelectedIndex = new Random().nextInt() % 3;
    Image temp = selected[clickedItemIndex];
    selected[clickedItemIndex] = playableCards.get(randomSelectedIndex);
    playableCards.set(randomSelectedIndex,temp);
}
```

Comment: I get `´;´ expected` Error after both voids. Is that not java or what am I missing?